# How to add files in /proc without using Loadable kernel module (LKM)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am trying to make some changes in the kernel of Linux and then want to print some debugging statements and also want to count some parameters in compile time of the kernel.

I want to store the content in /proc file how can I achieve this task and store the info in /proc file without using LKM.

Answer (score 0):

Using LKM approach is the best way to create proc entries and store the requisite info as "proc" itself is a filesystem provided by linux kernel for debugging purposes from user space.So, writing a module of your own using the proc related system calls would be easier and better for your purpose.Moreover, rather than building it as static module, you can compile it as a dynamic module to load and unload it at run-time.
If you don't want to use LKM, all the basic operations like proc_registration, creating entries,implementing read/write has to be done separately from scratch like writing your own system calls, registering it in kernel space and using them in your codes.